# Zend Framework 2: forward() to an AbstractRestfulController

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

In a regular AbstractActionController, you can use the forward controller plugin to forward the request to another controller under specification of that controller's name and some parameters, like

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $other_result = $this->forward()->dispatch('Application\Controller\Other', ['action' => 'doit']);
        return [
            'indexdata' => 'test',
            'otherdata' => $other_result
        ];
    }
}
```

I have implemented a restful API for the entities in our project using the `AbstractRestfulController`, and I figured I could just call the corresponding action on that controller i. e. when I want to update one of my models. That way I would not have to rewrite the CRUD logic a second time.

But is forwarding to an `AbstracRestfulController` even possible? Passing an action parameter to the `dispatch` method doesn't seem to be the solution, because the restful controller checks the request method (GET, POST, PUT etc.) to map the request to one of its restful methods (`get()`, `getList()`, `update()` or `create()`) instead of an action parameter. Of course one could just send an HTTP request to 'localhost' to invoke the restful controller, but that doesn't feel very elegant.

Another possibility I could think of to centralize the CRUD logic was creating a special service which will then be used in the restful controller and everywhere else I need to alter an entity. Is this the way to go? Or did I just miss how to forward to an `AbstractRestfulController`?

Comment: You can modify the request instance before you call `forward()`, i.e `$this->getRequest()->setMethod('POST');`